# Calculating the comparative value of a lease vs a purchase?

Tags: lease

I've got some company allowance toward home office costs, and there's a "preferred supplier" that - in the fine print - is actually leasing the equipment, not selling it.

If the RRP of purchasing a nice desk outright is $500,
but the desk is instead leased for 3 years,
how should I estimate the value I'd be receiving?
*(Desk goes back to the supplier if I leave the company or after the lease term is up, I don't pay monthly fees, there's no lease-to-own option)*

Comment: Does the company allowance cover the entire cost or are you having to pay some out-of-pocket? Would you want to replace the desk after 3 years even if it was purchased?

Comment: No idea what happens if the desired items are over that allowance, there's very little in the catalogue anyway.  I'm currently typing on a (too small) desk that I've had for 20+ years, so I wouldn't see a desk as a "depreciating" or temporary item.

Comment: From a financial standpoint, that's important to know  - i.e. would you spend more if you had to replace the leased desk in three years or would the company cover the full cost of a new desk? Generally you'd look at how much cash out of pocket you would pay in each scenario

Comment: If you're looking at depreciation, I presume this is a business item rather than a personal finance item... In my opinion, the only advantages of a lease are that you get a guaranteed buyer at the end of the depreciation period rather than having to find one (though not necessarily at a good price) and you don't have to take out a separate loan for the item (though the effective rate on the lease may nit be a good one; run the numbers.)

Comment: Why do you think the value is not zero?  The desk is never yours.  You don't get to keep it, but have to give it back.

Comment: @SimonB I agree it kinda stinks. I was hoping there was a mathematical way to express it. (value = $0 is hard to argue, ie you pay real money for a rented apartment even though it's never "yours")